# Lower than expected hashrates with HD7990

Tags: mining, hashrate

According to [mininghwcomparison.com](http://mininghwcomparison.com/list/index.php?brand=amd) I should be mining at around 44MHs with my HD7990 card (bought used very recently),  however I'm only getting between 10-15 (Genoils Ethminer). Is this expected? Is the data out of date on the above site?

I did notice on one other miner (Claymore) I tried that my card was reporting back as two 280x GPUs. Is this normal behaviour for this card, or has someone potentially been mod-ing it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is essentially what your card is. I know for sure it is two gpus on one board, so perhaps the 7970 and r9 280x are essentially the same gpu, so your 7990 is 2 r9 280x. Claymore does not differentiate or identify between rx 480 and 580 it labels either as rx480/580.

This may increase your hash rate if you havent done it already ; download the amd beta block chain driver(just enter that in google you will find it), It was made to fix the issue of cards slowing down as the dag increases, I have not been able to find a post from someone with a 7xxx  sharing their results although the driver lists these cards as supported so post your hashrate increase once youve changed drivers, for my polaris cards it increased the hashrate by 2-3mh/s each